# Continuous function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ tending to $\infty$ along each line through 0, but not uniformly in $\vert x \vert$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Does such a function exist, i.e. a function such that $f(rx) \to +\infty$ as $r \to +\infty$ for each $x \in S^1$, but not uniformly in $x$?

I initially thought it could not, by fixing some N and for each direction x on S1 taking R(x) to be such that at distance $\geq$ R in the direction of x, f is > N, and making a compactness argument to get an R that works for all directions. But even defining R(x) to be the smallest such in each case, R(x) is not necessarily continuous, so this approach doesn't work at all.

However I don't immediately spot an example either.

Comment: I do not understand what are you looking for... Could you explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)= (x^{2}-|y|)^{2}$ is one such function. Note that this function is bounded when $x^{2}=|y|$.